# jQuery AJAX on div not working after jQuery AJAX on another div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I have a page with 2 divs..each div have to call an ajax function on load. However, after I open either one of the divs, the ajax of the other div will not work.

*`#div_remove` lets the user delete a user from the system and display the existing ones in another div within #div_remove thru ajax.

`#div_logs` displays all transactions done in the system and displays them on another div within `#div_logs` through ajax.*

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$("#remove_admin").on("click",function(){
        $("#light").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#div_remove").slideDown("slow");
        showtable();
        event.preventDefault();

        $("#btnRemove").click(function(){
            var text = $.ajax ({
                type: "GET",
                url: "delUserProcess.php?keyword="+$("#txtRemove").val()+"&table=users&field=username",
                async: false,
            }).responseText;
            alert(text);
            showtable();
            event.preventDefault();
        });

    });

    //VIEW USER LOGS
    $("#logs").on("click",function(){
        $("#light").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#div_logs").slideDown("slow");
        showLogs(); 
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#txtUser").on("keyup",function(){
        showLogs(); 
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $(".date").on("change",function(){
        showLogs(); 
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});

function showtable(){
    $.ajaxSetup ({  
    cache: false  
}); 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "showAdmin.php",
        async: false,
        success:function(text){
            $("#tblUsers").html(text);
        }
    });

}

function showLogs(){
    $.ajaxSetup ({  
    cache: false  
}); 
    var cBy = $("#txtUser").val();
    var sDate = $("#startDate").val();
    var eDate = $("#endDate").val();


    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "showLogs.php?sDate="+sDate+"&eDate="+eDate+"&createdBy="+cBy,
        async: false,
        success: function(text){
            $("#tblHistory").html(text);
        }
    });

}`
```

the original code used `.click()`, `.keyup()` and `.change()`.. I already tried using `.live()` and `.on()` but it is still not working. please help.

Comment: it would be easier if you break it down and show just the relevant parts. is showLogs() one of the two divs?

Comment: showLogs() is just a function to call the ajax.. i put it in a function because i want to update the table each time there a keyup on the textbox and there's a change in the date textboxes too.

Comment: btw, i think the ajax is getting a response, but for some reason it is not being displayed in the divs..

Comment: any reason why using `async: false,`

Comment: i assigned false so that the ajax completes first before continuing.. do you think that might have been the cause? i'm still trying to learn different settings..

Comment: Well if you sent to `async: false` your execution thread will be blocked until server returns a response, it can not be considered as an AJAX request when `ASYNC: false`

Comment: to describe what exactly is happening, i have 2 buttons that will either display "#div_remove" or "#div_logs". If i open, for example, "#div_logs",ajax will work and it will load the table from an external php file.. inside the div, there's a back button which basically hides the div and brings me back to the 2 buttons.. if i click on the other button to display "#div_remove", it should call an ajax function to display another table but it doesnt display it..  the same thing happens regardless if i click on the div_remove first

Comment: ok so which one works and which one doesn't ? which method redraws the button? we may have a problem with the method that redraws the buttons

Comment: which ever i click on first, the first one will work but the other one doesnt.. the buttons are in the body of the main page.. the 2 divs are initially hidden but the two buttons shows them through jquery as well.. div_remove and div_logs has their own back button that hides the div..  here's the code of the back button $("input[value='Back']").click(function(){
   $("div").fadeOut("slow"); 
  });

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the events under the **`showLogs`** file.
Because whenever you call the delete or other events, it replace the html with the updated one. and the events lots it existance. So you need to call them in the **`showLogs`** file.

Comment: uhhm.. can u give me sample on how to do that?